# Can ViewBag be null in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

In MVC4, is it possible for `ViewBag` to ever be `null`? If so, under what scenarios could it be? If not, how do you know?

Specifically, I want to know if it can be `null` in a view. However, additional information about whether it can be `null` in a controller would be useful.

For example, do I need to perform a `null` check?

```
if (ViewBag != null && ViewBag.Something != null && ViewBag.Something.Foo == "Bar")
{
    // can ViewBag be null?
}
```

Comment: In a view or in a controller?

Comment: Either I suppose, but specifically in a view.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it can't.

The `ViewBag` property getter in `WebViewPage` looks like this:

```
public dynamic ViewBag
{
    get
    {
        if (_dynamicViewData == null)
        {
            _dynamicViewData = new DynamicViewDataDictionary(() => ViewData);
        }
        return _dynamicViewData;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried tracking this down myself, however all I could find is `public dynamic ViewBag { get; }` in `ViewMasterPage`. How did you locate this?

Answer (score 5):

`ViewBag` itself can't be null, so the first check

```
if (ViewBag != null)
```

is useless