# Will Using a .Clear On a Null ViewBag Cause An Error?

Tags: c#

I was told that if you used .Clear() on a null ViewBag would cause an error.

I tested it here and I set the ViewBag to null and ran it without any problem.
Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GmxctI

Is there anything to look out for before you clear a ViewBag?

Comment: Where are you setting viewbag to null?

Comment: The underlying `ViewBag` property itself is readonly as well, generally preventing you from setting it to null unless you really go out of your way using reflection etc

Comment: In a general sense though, it's right; if you use (nearly) anything on a null anything it will cause an error :)

Comment: This sounds like code review input you received. In general, calling a method on a null object would be an error. But, I found this related SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837423/can-viewbag-be-null-in-mvc4. The ViewBag is not normally null so you can .Clear() it with impunity.

Answer (score 2):

Empty and `null` are completely different things.

```
ViewBag = null;
```

This will set the ViewBag to null and you can no longer use it like this:

```
ViewBag["MyNumber"] = 1;
```

But if you call:

```
ViewBag.Clear();
```

Then that will erase any items in the ViewBag, but the object itself is still valid and new items can be added to it without error.

Comment: [`ViewBag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewbag?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) seems to be readonly property.

Comment: As James note in a comment in to the question you cannot assign null to the ViewBag property, so that edge case is taken care of :)

Comment: Possibly related SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837423/can-viewbag-be-null-in-mvc4